# Como hago una consulta en mysql que sume sólo los datos que no se repiten?

Tags: mysql

Necesito sumar la columna `insumos` de mi tabla `prestamos`, pero sólo una vez, no cada que se repitan. La tabla de la izquierda tiene todos los insumos:

```
SELECT insumo FROM prestamos, fruta where fruta.id_embarque=77 and prestamos.id_fruta=fruta.id
```

Y la de la derecha los datos normales sin repetirse que obtuve con:

```
select DISTINCT prestamos.insumo from prestamos, fruta where prestamos.id_fruta=fruta.id and fruta.id_embarque=77
```

Y necesito sólo el total de la tabla de la derecha

[image: Tablas]

Comment: puedes utilizar un GROUP BY en lugar de DISTINCT `select prestamos.insumo, SUM(prestamos.insumo) from prestamos, fruta where prestamos.id_fruta= fruta.id and fruta.id_embarque=77 GROUP BY prestamos.insumo`,

Comment: Podrías por favor colocar el ejemplo de lo que esperas obtener. Saludos.

Comment: @JosueArriola lo que espero es un solo número, la suma de todos los datos de  la tabla de la derecha

Comment: @AlejandraCervera es decir que básicamente sería una suma de la tabla `insumos`, pero ¿por qué haces join a la tabla `fruta`?. Saludos.

Comment: @JosueArriola porque la consulta es por embarques y ese dato está en la tabla fruta que está enlazada con prestamos por su id

Comment: Entiendo, voy a publicar una respuesta y me dices si te funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM( DISTINCT Precios) FROM Productos;
```

Comment: Considera leer [answer] y explicar tu código por favor

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación es que utilices una consulta agrupando por `insumo`, luego hacer la subconsulta con la suma, algo así:

```
select SUM(insumo) total_insumos 
from (SELECT insumo 
FROM prestamos
INNER JOIN fruta on fruta.id = prestamos.id_fruta
WHERE fruta.id_embarque = 77
GROUP BY insumo) x
```